# Jest. Change default export of imported module

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

I have a file **config.js** which looks and do pretty much this:

```
import publicConfig from './prod.keys';

const defaultConfig = {
   //...some default config
};

export default publicConfig || defaultConfig;
```

and **prod.keys.js**

```
// SOCIAL API KEYS FOR PRODUCTION
export default null;
```

Now I wonder if I can test that if someone exports a configuration from **prod.keys.js** then **config.js** file will return that config instead of default one?

Or maybe I shouldn't be testing things like this?